# Python sorting a list of strings

Tags: python, sorting

How would I sort this?

```
>>> list = ["a_0","a_1","a_2","a_3","a_10","a_11","a_23","a_5","a_6","a_5"]
>>> sorted(list)
['a_0', 'a_1', 'a_10', 'a_11', 'a_2', 'a_23', 'a_3', 'a_5', 'a_5', 'a_6']>
```

What I need it to be is:

```
['a_0', 'a_1', 'a_2', 'a_3', 'a_5', 'a_5', 'a_6, 'a_10', 'a_11', 'a_23']>
```

So it's sorted based on the "number".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

do you mean this: `sorted(list, key=lambda d: int(d[2:]))`   ?

Comment: Note that this will sort *only* based on the number, and not on the 'a' at all. It also requires that the digits start at character 2.

Comment: "Note that this will sort only based on the number", indeed

Answer (score 6):

You need to write a "key function" that translates your string into a search key that has the ordering you want. For example:

```
def key(k):
    s, sep, i = k.partition('_')
    return (s, int(i))

>>> L = ["a_0","a_1","b_2","c_2","a_10","a_11","a_23","b_5","a_6","c_5"]
>>> sorted(L, key=key)
['a_0', 'a_1', 'a_6', 'a_10', 'a_11', 'a_23', 'b_2', 'b_5', 'c_2', 'c_5']
```

Comment: thanks, this is actually what I needed for my exact purpose. I changed it a bit, now works perfect. Although your answer is correct, I have marked the answer above correct based on the question.